# Silently deleting a certificate from Windows Root Store

Tags: c++, windows, windows-services, certificate

I'm trying to delete a certificate from the **Root** store using *WinCrypt* API functions like this :

```
HANDLE hStoreHandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
PCCERT_CONTEXT pCertContext = NULL;
char * pszStoreName = "ROOT";
char pszNameString[256];

//hStoreHandle = CertOpenSystemStoreA(NULL, pszStoreName);

hStoreHandle = CertOpenStore(CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM,
        X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING,
        0,
        CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER,
        (LPVOID) L"Root");

if(hStoreHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        //Fail

while(pCertContext = CertEnumCertificatesInStore(hStoreHandle, pCertContext))
{
    if(CertGetNameStringA(   
        pCertContext,   
        CERT_NAME_SIMPLE_DISPLAY_TYPE,   
        0,
        NULL,   
        pszNameString,   
        256))
    {
        if(strcmp(pszNameString, "DummyCertificate") == 0)
        {
            if(!CertDeleteCertificateFromStore(
                CertDuplicateCertificateContext(pCertContext))
                )   
            {
                //Fail
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Fail
    }
}
```

This happens in a function that is called when my application, a *Windows Service*, is registered with `MyService.exe /Service`. So, in theory, it should have all the necessary access it needs to delete a certificate. However, when the `CertDeleteCertificateFromStore` function is called, a popup window appears that asks the user if he really wants to delete the certificate.

I'm trying to prevent this window from appearing and delete the certificate silently if found. Any suggestions?

I've looked into the command line utilities `certutil` and `certmgr`. As I understand it from the Internet, `certutil` is somewhat limited on client machines and `certmgr` doesn't allow deletion of Root cetificates. I would like a programmatic solution but I'm fine with using a tool if it gets the job done.

Answer (score -1):

You can do a hack by auto-answering the dialog through your program. Try finding the button window associated with the dialog in another thread & post message to generate BN_CLICKED event on the "yes" button.

Comment: On slower (older) systems wouldn't it cause the window to be drawn before the event is fired? I really don't want the window to appear in any way.

Comment: Most driver software uses this method to hide the "Driver unsigned" dialog. It works good though the window may come & go away immediately in a flash.

Comment: I'll give it a try but I will let the question open for a few days. If it works I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I would say this is an extremely un-ethical thing to do. People like to be in control over security critical parts of their system. There's a UI prompt for a reason

Comment: @sehe It's used as a response to remove fake certificates. I wouldn't think it's unethical. A less experienced user might panic and will choose not to delete it. He might be a victim of man-in-the-middle attacks. Notifications might be used to let the user know what's happening and backups can be made of the deleted certificates. The ethical conclusion is drawn from the purpose of the end result software, not the action of deleting certificates.

Comment: You can't be a good guy by hiding sensitive prompts. You can ask for elevated permissions up front, though which might give you enough permissions

Comment: Except the process that deletes the certificate is running as a Windows Service. What higher permissions do you need in User-Mode to delete a certificate? Can you open a chat about this, I can describe what the problem is further if you're not convinced.

Comment: Besides I was asking if it can be done, not if it's ethical to do it. I need an objective answer, not if I will hurt someone's feelings by deleting a certificate.

Comment: @Sebastian-LaurenţiuPlesciuc I didn't comment on the question. I commented on this answer, as it appears to advocate a particularly dangerous brand of unethical band-aid. _(You can ask, and we can comment. It's a beautiful world)_

Answer (score -1):

```
CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER->CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE
```

Comment: Can you provide some context for how your answer can be used to solve the question? One line of text with no explanation does not provide a good answer.